# Pull out variable and common denominator from fraction

Tags: polynomials, factorization

I have this code:

```
K[Q_, n_Integer] := 
 Module[{z, x}, 
  SymmetricReduction[
     SeriesCoefficient[
      Product[ComposeSeries[Series[Q[z], {z, 0, n}], 
        Series[x[i] z, {z, 0, n}]], {i, 1, n}], n], 
     Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}], Table[Subscript[c, i], {i, 1, n}]][[1]] //
    FactorTerms]

   poly = K[Sqrt[#]/Tanh[Sqrt[#]] &, 8] /. c -> p;
   primeFactorForm[n_] := 
   If[Length@# == 1, First@#, CenterDot @@ #] &[Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n]];

   For[i = 0, i < 5, i++, 
   poly = K[Sqrt[#]/Tanh[Sqrt[#]] &, i] /. c -> p;  
   Print[Subscript[L, i], " = ", 
   Plus @@ List @@ Expand[poly] /. 
   Times[Rational[n_, d_], e__] :> 
   primeFactorForm[n]/ primeFactorForm[d]*e]]
```

Which outputs some polynomials of the form:

$L_2 = \frac{p_1^2-1^1}{ 5^1 \cdot 3^2}+\frac{7^1 p_2}{5^1\cdot 3^2 }$

How can I put the variable out of the fraction? I want to obtain something like: 
$L_2 = \frac{-1^1}{ 5^1 \cdot 3^2}p_1^2+\frac{7^1 }{5^1\cdot 3^2 }p_2$ Thank you!

Comment: You can use collect command.

Comment: @GopalVerma Where exactly should I add that? I see that Collect requires a variable but my polynomial has many (it is not just a polynomial in x)

Comment: Can you provide your  polynomial?

Comment: I gave an example of one of them in my post. They look more or less the same for higher terms, just with more parameters not just p1 and p2 and also crossed terms i.e. p1*p3

Comment: Did you try Expand[poly]?

Comment: @GopalVerma I am using that in the 3rd line from bottom to top. Should I add it to some other place, too?

Comment: Using Distribute[poly] // Expand  expression is expanded in term of p1..p2...and cross term (little bit different form). May be it is useful for you.

Comment: @GopalVerma Replacing Expand with Distribute on the 3rd line from bottom to top, doesn't do it. Should I add it somewhere else, too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74138/discussion-between-gopal-verma-and-silviu).